# unable to create zoho oauth client id with global scope

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, zoho

zoho oauth client_id is not working for multiple users. It works for only those users who are added in my zoho crm account . i want to integrate the zoho mail.

Answer (score 1):

> **APIs OAuth configuration in ZOHO developer console:**

I would like to inform you that the **ZOHO** provides **Oauth** scopes at application level and not at global level.
So you needs to create new scope with **ZOHO Mail** app and it will provide you different **ClientId** and **ClientSecret** from your **ZOHO CRM** for accessing a **Mail** app services.

**For example:** If you need to implement this in another app then first of all, configure this app at **ZOHO developer console** configuration. After that, you can access those services.

[image]